# long polling netty nio framework java

Tags: java, asynchronous, nio, long-polling, netty

How can I do long-polling using [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) framework? Say for example I fetch `http://localhost/waitforx`

but `waitforx` is asynchronous because it has to wait for an event? Say for example it fetches something from a blocking queue(can only fetch when data in queue). When getting item from queue I would like to sent data back to client. Hopefully somebody can give me some tips how to do this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write a response header first, and then send the body (content) later from other thread.

```
void messageReceived(...) {
    HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse(...);
    res.setHeader(...);
    ...
    channel.write(res);
}

// In a different thread..
ChannelBuffer partialContent = ...;
channel.write(partialContent);
```

Comment: Does this actually work? Can you write to a channel from another thread? It's thread-safe?

Comment: How does the "different thread" know which channel to use? For example, client1 does a long poll, do I have to put the channel in a HashMap<clientId,Channel> and fetch it once the event has occurred so that I can send the partial content?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) project. It's implementation of [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) server with long polling support. On web side you can use [Socket.IO client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) javascript lib.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following in [sfnrpc]: http://code.google.com/p/sfnrpc

```
Object object = RPCClient.getInstance().invoke("#URN1","127.0.0.1:6878","echo",true,60,"", objArr,classArr, sl);
```

The true causes communication to be synchronous.