# send message netty with javascript

Tags: javascript, netty

Is there any way for sending messages to a netty http server from javascript like a WebSocket object but for Netty long polling ?

Comment: have you find any method for this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294010/long-polling-netty-nio-framework-java).
I put an example of long polling in a test project called [netty-ajax-server](https://github.com/nickman/netty-ajax-server). If you browse the source code, you will find the pipeline factory, handler and javascript client implementation.